# Converting Moment utc time into unix time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello guys I was wondering how do I convert a date into Unix time stamp using the library moment.js so I can compare the oldDate with another date.

This is what I tried:

```js
var oldDate = (moment.unix(1490632174)).format();
// here I got the Date in string format
var newDate= moment.utc('2017-03-27T18:29:59+02:00', "YYYY-MM-DD");
// now I want to convert it again into unix timestamp and I don't know how to do it.
console.log(oldDate, newDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why now capture moment and use it twice? `now = moment` `newDate=now.utc(...)` `stamp=now.unix()`

Comment: Your snippet was not running at all, I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documentation is a wonderful thing. [Unix Timestamp (seconds)](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/)

> moment().unix();
>
> moment#unix outputs a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch).
>
> moment(1318874398806).unix(); // 1318874398
>
> This value is floored to the nearest second, and does not include a milliseconds component.

```js
var oldDate = moment.unix(1490632174).unix();
// here I got the Date in string format
var newDate= moment.utc('2017-03-27T18:29:59+02:00', "YYYY-MM-DD");
// now I want to convert it again into unix timestamp and I don't know how to do it.
console.log(oldDate, newDate.unix());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<` and `>` operators:

```js
var oldDate = moment.unix(1490632174);
var newDate= moment.utc('2017-03-27T18:29:59+02:00', "YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(oldDate<newDate, oldDate>newDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could approach this is to leverage the native `Date.parse("2017-03-27T18:29:59+02:00 GMT")` method in Javascript. This method parses a date string and returns Unix Time in ms.

For more info, checkout [Date.parse() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and this [Unix Time Converter](https://timeconverter.ca) that makes use of both moment and the native JS method.